# Retrieve and replace value in a dict with a single lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lookup

When I wish to both retrieve *and* replace a value in a dict, I naively write:

```
old_value = my_dict['key']
my_dict['key'] = new_value
```

But.. that's two lookups for `'key'` in `my_dict` hashtable. And I'm sure that only one is necessary.

How do I get the same behaviour with only one lookup?
Does python automately JIT-optimizes this away?

---

[EDIT]: I am aware that python dict lookup is cheap and that performance gain would be quite anecdotic unless `my_dict` is huge or the operation is done billions times a milisecond.
I am just curious about this apparently-basic feature being implemented or not in python, like an `old_value = my_dict.retrieve_and_replace('key', new_value)`.

Comment: you never use `old_value`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I do. I need to tell it `old_value.forget()` or `old_value.you_have_been_moved()`, `old_value.die()`, `old_value.take_a_new_start()` or things like that :)

Comment: Can you create a minimal example in the questoin that illustrates your actual issue? Also dict look-ups are pretty cheap, is this really a bottleneck for your code?

Comment: @Chris_Rands It is not. I confess this is pure nit-picking 0:) I'm just curious.

Comment: @Chris_Rands As for the minimal example. I haven't though about boiling my script down to it for now. But I think it is quite common for objects like `old_value` to have to log their removal or cast a last event before they get ready for gc, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a reference rather than a value in the dict will do what you want. This isn't intended to be an elegant demonstration, just a simple one:

```
>>> class MyMutableObject(object):
        pass
>>> m = MyMutableObject()
>>> m.value = "old_value"
>>> my_dict["k"] = m
```

Now when you want to change `my_dict["k"]` to a new value but remember the old one, with a single lookup on `"k"`:

```
>>> m2 = my_dict["k"]
>>> m2.value
'old_value'
>>> m2.value = 'new_value'
```

It's up to you to decide if the price this pays in complexity is worth the time saving of one dictionary lookup. Dereferencing `m2.value` and assigning it afresh will cost 2 more dictionary lookups under the hood.

Comment: I am quite surprised, because I was expecting something more python-primitive-looking, but I must say that it does the trick :)